# Question about unwrapping in Java if memory mutation happens

Tags: java

When we unwrap a Wrapper object to its respective primitive value such as Integer to int, does it make a new value to be stored into the int, where it is 4 bytes (the size of 4 bytes), or does it mutate the value inside the Integer and shorten its memory size to be converted to an int?

Comment: 1) `Integer x = 12; int y = 8; y = x` write this code and then use `javap` to see what the compiler really does, and it's called "unbox", not "unwrap." 2) an Object can't be converted to a primitive the way you think about it, `Integer` is not "shorten" to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I / we assume that you mean [*unboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) when you say unwrapping.

The answer is that no "memory mutation" occurs for the object that is being unboxed.

1. The wrapper classes are immutable<sup>1</sup>.  Therefore nothing *could* occur that changes the object's visible state.
2. The JLS states that unboxing of (say) an `Integer` to an `int` is equivalent to calling `Integer.intValue()`.  The javadoc for `Integer.intValue()` makes no mention of mutation.
3. In general, there is actually no need to mutate an object in order to convert its value.  Any non-trivial conversion can be performed using *local variables* to hold any intermediate state needed; e.g.

   ```
    SomeType convertToSomeType() {
        // Copy this.state variables to local variables
        // Convert using local variables
        return /* some value created from the local variables */
   ```
4. An examination of the source code of `java.lang.Integer` shows that it is implemented as follows<sup>2</sup>:

   ```
   public int intValue() {
       return value;
   }
   ```

   There is no mutation there.
5. There is no way to shorten the memory size of a simple Java object at the JVM level.  Heap nodes don't grow or shrink.
6. If (hypothetically!) it was possible to shrink a Java heap node, the heap node size is a multiple of 8 bytes.  So (say) reducing the value in an `Integer` from 4 bytes to 2 bytes would not actually result in a smaller heap node.
7. If (hypothetically!) there was a practical way to optimize memory usage for an `Integer` or any other wrapper class, the optimization *should* be done when creating the wrapper object (or mutating it if that was allowed) ... not when unwrapping it.

---

<sup>1 - I was surprised to discover that neither the JLS or the javadocs state this explicitly.  However, it is clear from what they do say that the standard primitive wrapper classes must be immutable.  For example, if `Integer` values were mutable the `Integer` caching behavior that is specified in the the JLS would be unsound.</sup>

<sup>2 - White lie.  In some versions of Java there is a `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation on the method.  But it is implausible that what ever the JIT compiler *might* do would involve mutating the `Integer` object.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When you unwrap a wrapper object there is an implicit call to a method which returns the primitive type the object holds. In the case of `Integer` the called method is [`intValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue()). So for example. Read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 0):

"Unwrapping" an Integer object copies the 4-byte `int` value from inside it to a new memory location.

The Integer object is not changed in any way.

Comment: A class being final does not mean it's immutable

Comment: oh my! I was thinking in an entirely different perspective, my comment indeed makes no sense, will remove